# Interfacing an RCA audio output to a microcontroller ADC

Tags: microcontroller, audio, adc

I'd like to connect the audio output from a set-top box (and similar) to a microcontroller's ADC. They all have an RCA connector so I was wondering what sort of circuit may be required to interface the RCA audio output to the ADC on a microcontroller?

Comment: Yes ,I only want to take audio  directly from Set-top box via microcontroller.

Comment: @user40646, I've removed the confusing RF part and narrowed it down to just the hardware aspect. If this question is re-opened and answered how to take the samples on a particular microcontroller would be best as a new question if you run into any problems on that side (give it a go yourself first though).

Comment: There are tons of off the shelf solutions to this problem. Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: Have you found the RCA component you needed for this? It would have to be able to connect to the microcontroller. Doesn't it have to have a specific way to connect to the microcontroller? Or just two wires like any standard RCA jack you get off the shelf?

Answer (score 9):

Here is something to try:

[image]

Audio signals meant to go between equipment but not directly from microphones or meant to drive a speaker are usually at *line level*, which is usually around 1 V RMS.  That is about the right amplitude for driving a microcontroller A/D input, but the DC level needs to be set close to half of the A/D range.  This is what R2 and R3 do in this circuit.

C1 decouples the DC level of the input signal from that at the A/D input.  R1 provides a little optional attenuation in case the audio level is too high and ends up clipping against the A/D limit too often.

Note that R2 and R3 together provide 50 kΩ of impedance as seen by the A/D input.  The high pass filter formed by C1 and this impedance has a rolloff of 16 Hz, which is low enough to pass "HiFi" audio acceptably.